# mvc 4 beginform with route name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm generating a form in MVC using `@Html.BeginForm()`, but my form has to post to my confirmation action which will render the confirmation view.

The confirmation action is easy enough to get to, but the user will be redirected there as well and my mapped route looks like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "RegisterConfirmationRoute",
        url: "register/confirmation",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ConfirmRegistration" }
    );
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? 
I don't see how I can get `@Html.BeginForm` to use the routeName to render the form's action attribute?

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want `Html.BeginRouteForm("RegisterConfirmationRoute")`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
Html.BeginForm("ConfirmRegistration", "Account")
```

Am i misunderstanding your question?

Comment: This works too, but it seems the BeginRouteForm is the more appropriate option. Thanks Jaminto